# if any one of two approvers approve, the workflow status wil be cnaged to approved in approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

i designed a approval process on employee leave request

but here in leave request approval there is two approver users

1)primary approver1

2) secondary approver2

below is the process flow :

1--employee1  requested for leave he open the new list item and fill the data

2--- primary approver1 , secondary approver2  shld receive the employee1 leave request

(for both task list will be created)

3--- primary approver1  will approve the request and workflow status  will be approved and forwared the request for HR

here in case  primary approver1  will not available  secondary approver2  will approve the request  and workflow status  will be approved and forwared the request for HR

in this case if any one of them approve  current request will be approved,

in my case  how to design a workflow

here i added aproval process to two users by parallel

and task  list created for both users  and worflow status changed to approved if both usrs approve, but i need any one of them approve , the workflow status cnaged to approved

Answer (score 1):

You can choose sequential workflow approach or you can even add a condition before the block from where the workflow move towards HR, that

`if primaryApproverOutcome & secondaryApproverOutcome == 'Approved'`

then only workflow go further.

Hope this may give you some direction.